# Customise section with koma script

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, section-titles

I wonder if you could offer some help. I want to customise the section titles in a `scrbook` class document. Something similar to this:
[image]

Section number in a box followed by a centred line Section name and another vertically centred line filling the text width.

So far, I have searched for solutions in this StackExchange but with no success. I have checked the [Koma-Script manual](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) and found two possible commands to do something similar:  `\sectionformat` and `\sectionlinesformat`. But honestly, my very limited knowledge of latex does not allow me to understand when to use one or the other.

Looking at similar solutions found in this forum, I manage to have this:

```
\documentclass[openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,twoside, margin=3cm}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
    \usekomafont{section}
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\fboxrule=1.5pt\fcolorbox{black}{white!0}{\color{black}\thesection}\rule[.7ex]{10pt}{1.5pt}}
 }

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \section{Section 1}
    \Blindtext[2]
    \section{Section 2}
    \Blindtext[2]
    \section{Section 3}
    \Blindtext[2]
    \section{Section 4}
    \Blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

from which I get:
[image]

But I have not found a way to add the horizontal-vertical text height aligned line to fill the text width.

Another option I tried was using:

```
%%%%% Simple + underline
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
\Ifstr{#1}{section}{%
    \parbox[c]{\linewidth}{%
      \raggedsection{\hskip #2{\color{black}#3}}{#4}\par%
      \kern-.75\ht\strutbox\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}%
    }%
  }{%
    {\hskip #2#3}{#4}}% 
}
```

See, here `\sectionlinesformat` is used instead of `\sectionformat`, but no idea why.
For which I get:

[image]

A third option I found was using `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[-\dimexpr\fboxsep+2pt\relax]{\columnwidth}{1.5pt}}%
  \colorbox{blue}{%
    \rule[-2pt]{0pt}{0pt}%
    \color{white}\csname the#1\endcsname
  }%
  \quad
}
\makeatother
```

And I get:

[image]

Any guidance on how can I get the desired result?

Also, It would be nice if we can have the option to have the section number and its box aligned with the text or on the margin.

Comment: Should subsections and subsubsections use the same format and color as sections? Are there section headings that require two or more lines? How should they be formatted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,twoside, margin=3cm}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xhfill}

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
    \usekomafont{section}%
    \fboxrule=1pt\fcolorbox{blue}{white!0}{\color{black}\thesection}%
    \color{blue}\rule[.7ex]{10pt}{1pt}\>%
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{\color{blue}#4}\>%
    \xrfill[.7ex]{1pt}[blue]%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \section{Section 1}
    \Blindtext[2]
    \section{Section 2}
    \Blindtext[2]
    \section{Section 3}
    \Blindtext[2]
    \section{Section 4}
    \Blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It definitely solves the problem. I couple of questions if you allow me:
1. I ran the code as you wrote, but It did not work in my code, I had to put the \> in math mode -->   $\>$. 
2. I have read that people discourage using makeatletter/makeatother (not clear for me why anyway). In your solution, I think you use it because it requires the use of \@hangfrom. what @\hangfrom command does?
3. I see \sectionlinesformat command requires 4 entries, from them I found out #4 is the section name, but I could not figure out what are #1, #2 and #3, do you have an idea that these represent?

Comment: @JuanGuerrero-Fernández 1. `\>` is just a space so it shouldn't change anything. You could also change it to another space if you prefer.

Comment: 2. and 3. Indeed, `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are required here because of `\@hangfrom`. To understand what these two commands do, see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/201628). For `\@hangfrom`,  in fact I don't know exactly what it does, I just know that it's basically the default version of `\sectionlinesformat` (for details about that command and its arguments, see page 498 of the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrbook) of `scrbook`). To redefine `\sectionlinesformat`, I just copied the default version and added the line on the right.

Comment: `\@hangfrom` is for the alignment of headings with two or more text lines. Note that `\sectionlinesformat` is also used for other free-standing headings  `subsection` and `subsubsection` (except `chapter` and `part`).  So they will have also blue text followed by a blue line.

Answer (score 2):

Only as addition to the answer of @Vincent:

If only sections (and not subsections and subsubsections) should use the different format:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside,open=right]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=3cm}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xhfill}

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \fboxrule=1.5pt\fcolorbox{.}{white}{\color{black}\thesection}%
  \rule[.7ex]{10pt}{1pt}\;%
}

\NewCommandCopy{\originalsectionlinesformat}{\sectionlinesformat}
\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4\Ifstr{#1}{section}{\;\xrfill[.6ex]{1.5pt}[.]}{}}%
}

\addtokomafont{section}{\color{blue!50!black}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\Blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If subsections and subsubsections should use the same format but different colors:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside,open=right]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=3cm}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xhfill}

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \fboxrule=1.5pt\fcolorbox{.}{white}{\normalcolor\thesection}%
  \rule[.7ex]{10pt}{1pt}\;%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
  \fboxrule=1.5pt\fcolorbox{.}{white}{\normalcolor\thesubsection}%
  \rule[.7ex]{10pt}{1pt}\;%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
  \fboxrule=1.5pt\fcolorbox{.}{white}{\normalcolor\thesubsubsection}%
  \rule[.7ex]{10pt}{1pt}\;%
}

\NewCommandCopy{\originalsectionlinesformat}{\sectionlinesformat}
\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4\;\xrfill[.6ex]{1.5pt}[.]}%
}

\addtokomafont{section}{\color{blue!50!black}}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\color{green!50!black}}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\color{red!50!black}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\Blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]